# Java, Gradle, CI, and specifying memory usage limits

Tags: java, android, command-line, gradle, continuous-integration

I'm running Robolectric test cases in a CI environment, which sets an upper limit of 4gigs across all containers.  Since my test cases have grown, so has the memory usage apparrently.

I can no longer run a successful test/build because of a process that continues to take me over the memory limit.

I have tried to configure Gradle using the following gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

However, the first process is still using 4gigs.  Here is the usage dump.

```
  PID  RSS     %CPU COMMAND
  5663 4360612 60.0 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -javaagent:/home/ubuntu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.newrelic.agent.android/class-rewriter/3.407.0/6f7f95a36369f76b739461331202406fa1f519c7/class-rewriter-3.407.0.jar -Dandroid.assets=/home/ubuntu/Android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -Dandroid.manifest=/home/ubuntu/Android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -Dandroid.resources=/home/ubuntu/Android/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -Djava.security.manager=jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ea -cp /home/ubuntu/.gradle/caches/1.10/workerMain/gradle-worker.jar jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain
  5277 395868  67.3 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /usr/local/gradle-1.10/lib/gradle-launcher-1.10.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 1.10 /home/ubuntu/.gradle/daemon 120000 99e43642-9137-411a-ba62-f82d964a2f89 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
  5237 305076  4.3  /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle -classpath /usr/local/gradle-1.10/lib/gradle-launcher-1.10.jar org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain --info --project-dir /home/ubuntu/Android/app test
```

Is there any way I can configure that first process to not use so much memory?  Also, if there is no swap space available on this environment, will limiting the memory usage just cause an OOM error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory limits for test JVMs can be configured via:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxHeapSize = "512m"
    jvmArgs "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
}
```

It remains to be seen if this solves the problem, though.

Comment: I threw maxHeapSize into the DSL container (which just happened to be robolectric), if it was unspecified, it was allocating 25% of 32GB, which blew the limit. Thanks